# Blank Page Shown when Deploying React App to gh pages with a Custom Domain

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, custom-domain

I successfully deployed my portfolio website onto GitHub pages and everything was working. So I thought I should use a personal domain for it (I bought at get.tech)

I also set up the A & CName records to point to github-pages ip addresses:

A Records:

```js
1            130642964      kevinf.tech     185.199.108.153     Active   


2            130642965      kevinf.tech     185.199.109.153     Active   


3            130642966      kevinf.tech     185.199.110.153     Active   


4            130642967      kevinf.tech     185.199.111.153     Active
```

CNAME Records:

```js
    www.kevinf.tech     hfang821.github.io      Active
```

I insert a "CNAME" file at the root level of the repo as well.
After I put my "kevinf.tech" into the custom domain field in the github pages, it showed that the site is live. But when I clicked into it, it's just a empty page (but favicon is shown lol).

Is it some steps that I did not do to set it up correctly?

my repo: https://github.com/hfang821/react_portfolio_v2

[devtool screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQp6I.png)

Comment: I don't think you should point your record to the IP address of your GitHub repo, instead point it to the address itself.

Comment: The CNAME record? I did point it to my GitHub address though.